# Boost BGL thread safety

Tags: c++, boost, graph, thread-safety, shortest-path

I'd like multiple threads to use the dijkstra_shortest_paths and astar_search functions of the BGL, and then read the property maps of the result vertices and edges.

I'm wondering wether I should use mutexes to ensure thread-safety.

So here are my questions:

1., Are the dijkstra_shortest_paths and astar_search functions of the Boost.Graph thread safe?

2., If I only try to read the property maps of the graph from multiple threads, do I need to worry about thread safety?

Answer (score 1):

Property maps and the BGL are not thread-safe as of now. For reference see [this post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/03/163438.php).

Comment: Take a look at Parallel BGL (PBGL), it can run as multiple processes on a single host (via MPI). http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/graph_parallel/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what question 1 is about, but BGL data structures have the same thread safety as the STL containers (i.e., separate containers cannot share data structures in thread-unsafe ways but operations on a single container need to be synchronized).  As to question 2, read-only access to properties is safe from multiple threads as long, at least with the BGL-provided property map types.